# tense problem about the use of modal verbs

Tags: verbs, modal-verbs

I have been reading the Harry Potter series recently, and here are three examples of the use of modal verbs:

1. What could he have been thinking of？It must have been a trick of the light.
2. He'd never even seen the boy. It might have been Harvey. Or Harold.
3. But then it struck Mr.Dursley that this was probably some silly stunt—these people were obviously collecting for something... yes, that would be it.

Thay all express Mr.Dursley's thoughts by the author's speech, and the first two both use a 'have' after 'must' and 'might' to refer to past tense. Similarly, should the last sentence in the third example be 'that would have been it'?

Comment: Mr Dursley thought "That's it - they were collecting for something." He thought of an explanation for something that had happened earlier, so the tense is not the same.

Comment: @Kate Thank you for your comment. However, in your opinion, the first sentence should be "this had probably been some silly stunt". Right?

Comment: Logically, yes, but it can make a sentence rather cumbersome to keep using the past perfect when the meaning is clear without it.

Comment: @Kate Thanks. That is to say, the first two examples express Mr.Dursley's thoughts by the author's speech, while the third uses his own speech by using the hyphen, which plays the same role as quotation marks. Am I right?

Comment: It's a dash rather than a hyphen, but, yes, that's what he was 'saying' to himself.

Comment: @Kate Mr Dursley thought "That would it - they are collecting for something." , and the sentence after the dash is indirect speech. I think this is actually the right explanation, cuz direct speech is often used with quotes or italics.